# Link to Anchor under Fixed Header from Another Page

Tags: jquery, scroll, window, anchor

I'm trying to link to an anchor on one page (Page 1) from another one (Page 2). Both pages have a fixed header. As such, I'm using the follow script on both pages:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.testlink').bind('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var sHref = this.href.split("#"); 
        var topDistance = $("#"+sHref[1]).position().top;
        var tds = topDistance - 146 ;
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: tds }, 'slow');            
        return false;           
    });
});
```

Example link:

```
<a href="../plan/medical.html#howdeductworks">How the deductible works</a>
```

Example anchor link:

```
<a id="howdeductworks"></a>
```

This links to the anchor, then offsets it, so that the anchor isn't under the header.

When I link to an anchor from Page 1 to an anchor on Page 1, everything works fine. When I link to one on another page, the script doesn't work and anchor is underneath the header.

I tried recoding it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.testlink').bind('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); 
        $(location).attr( 'href', $(this).attr('href') );
        var sHref = this.href.split("#"); 
        var topDistance = $("#"+sHref[1]).position().top;
        var tds = topDistance - 146 ;
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: tds }, 'slow');
        return false;           
    });
});
```

...but that didn't work. Perhaps I wrote what I wanted to do incorrectly. If so, I would appreciate some help.

BTW, as mentioned above, when click to an anchor from the link on the same page, the page doesn't refresh - it just goes to the anchor. I'd like for that to stay, if possible (meaning no refresh). If the link is coming from another page, yes, refresh/load the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
    function scrollToAnchor(anchor) {
            $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(anchor).position().top - 146 }, 'slow');
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.testlink').bind('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault(); 
            var sHref = this.href.split("#"); 
            scrollToAnchor("#"+sHref[1]);
            return false;           
        });

        //now scroll to the anchor when loading page - this was missing
        scrollToAnchor(document.location.hash);
    });
```

Comment: It worked for a split second...then it snapped back to the top. I eventually removed the function from animate, and it went right to it. Can you explain why I would need that? Doesn't 'anchor" already capture that value? Thanks for the assist.

Comment: Quite right. It should not be needed here - a left over from another project.

Comment: Cool. I was getting an error in IE saying "'position().top' is null or not an object". I modified the code to this: if(window.location.hash != ''){ scrollToAnchor(window.location.hash); } ...and that solved the problem. Thanks again.